# How do you add a new entry into the django admin index?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm working on a Django project, and I've created some custom admin views using the [get_urls override method described in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls). It works perfectly. There is just one problem. There is no way to get to this custom admin view unless you already know the URL.

There are some ways I already know of to add a link to this view somewhere in the admin, but none of them are satisfactory. I want a link to the custom view to appear in the model listings right with all the model admins. I just don't want it to have +add or +change links next to it because it isn't a model.

I could just override the admin_site or the template, but this is no good. It puts the customization on the project level instead of the app level. It also will only put the link on the /admin/ page and not the /admin/myapp/ page.

I could also just easily add the link in a different location by overriding the app_index.html template, but that is not exactly a convenient or intuitive place to look for it.

Another solution I came up with is to create a blank model and register a blank admin for it. Then steal the url patterns for that model so clicking on its entry goes to my custom view instead of to a blank add/change view. That works, but it's an incredibly ugly hack.

Here is a picture of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: Customized Django Admin List]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still think the correct way of doing this is overwriting some parts of django admin templates. There is no easy way of adding these links.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template

I also found this article http://coffeeonthekeyboard.com/o-hai-django-adminplus-568/ which also suggests that django-adminplus is a good tool for doing this. Personally I prefer to keep clear of any extra dependancies and would still use templates - but thats up to you.

Comment: I already know how to override the templates. None of them I know of on the app level will put the link in that place.

Comment: Well actually if you edit the templates correctly then you can put anything anywhere. Just check with an if statement for the correct app name in the template.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/index.html

This is the index template and it has a for loop:
{% for app in app_list %} so you check for the correct app and if correct then insert your links after the last loop.

It's doable but yes not that nice looking.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this app: https://github.com/jsocol/django-adminplus? Even if it does not work for the exact purpose you are trying to achieve, at least it can give you some enlightement by checking out the code

Comment: At first this looked promising, but you can clearly see this screenshot, it does not do what I'm looking for. http://i.imgur.com/UmODn.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to [override the template admin/index.html](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/#customize-the-admin-index-page). Thenput a new pair of  tags after the [{% endfor %} on line 40](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/index.html#L40).

You might also be able to solve it using jQuery.