# Add a link to custom django admin view

Tags: django, django-admin

I've created a custom admin view as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites).

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            path('stats/', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.stats)),
        ]
        return my_urls + urls

    def stats(self, request):
        request.current_app = self.admin_site.name

        context = dict(
           # Include common variables for rendering the admin template.
           self.admin_site.each_context(request),
           # Anything else you want in the context...
           key='blah',
        )
        return TemplateResponse(request, "sometemplate.html", context)
```

The URL is working and the template is loading. 
But how, can I get a link to my new custom view into the overview of the Django admin?

[image]

Comment: I think that the ModelAdmin is meant to work for a model, so in order to make it appear in the index you need to register it with admin.site.register().
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial07/#customize-the-admin-index-page

Answer (score 2):

There is already a similar question [How do you add a new entry into the django admin index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975218/how-do-you-add-a-new-entry-into-the-django-admin-index), but all of the provided answers were not very satisfying for me.

Therefore I ran through the source code and was looking for a possibility which wouldn't involve overriding any templates, neither `index.html` nor `app_index.html`.

The file [`django/contrib/admin/sites.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py) holds the code responsible for rendering `index.html` and `app_index.html`, the first is the template that displays what is illustrated in the question.

The method [`index`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L494) renders the template `index.html` and displays the available apps with the registered model admins. It uses the method [`get_app_list`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L477) to get the apps. Within this method the method [`_build_app_dict`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L409) is called, which gets the models and the model admins.

The method [`app_index`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L512) renders the template `app_index.html` and displays the registered model admins for a single app. It uses the method [`_build_app_dict`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L409), mentioned before.

Thus I decided to override this method in my custom admin. Based on the example in the question it can look like this (differences to the original example are shown in bold):

```
class MyAdmin(admin.AdminSite):
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            path('stats/', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.stats), name='stats'),
        ]
        return my_urls + urls

    def stats(self, request):
        request.current_app = self.admin_site.name

        context = dict(
           # Include common variables for rendering the admin template.
           self.admin_site.each_context(request),
           # Anything else you want in the context...
           key='blah',
        )
        return TemplateResponse(request, "sometemplate.html", context)

    def _build_app_dict(self, request, label=None):
        # we create manually a dict to fake a model for our view 'stats'
        # this is an example how the dict should look like, i.e. which keys
        # should be present, the actual values may vary
        stats = {
            'name': 'Stats',
            'admin_url': reverse('my_admin:stats'),
            'object_name': 'Stats',
            'perms': {'delete': False, 'add': False, 'change': False},
            'add_url': ''
        }
        # get the app dict from the parent method
        app_dict = super(MyAdmin, self)._build_app_dict(request, label)
        # check if there is value for label, then the app_index will be rendered
        if label:
            # append the manually created dictionary 'stats'
            app_dict['models'].append(stats)
        # otherwise the index will be rendered
        # and we have to get the entry for our app,
        # which is in this case 'traffic'
        # using TrafficConfig.name or TrafficConfig.label
        # might be better than hard coding the value
        else:
            app = app_dict.get('traffic', None)
            # if an entry for 'traffic' has been found
            # we append our manually created dictionary
            if app:
                app['models'].append(stats)
        return app_dict

my_admin = MyAdmin(name='my_admin')
my_admin.register(Traffic)
```

Now when we open our custom admin we'll see something like this:

```
TRAFFIC
---------------------------------  
  Traffics    + Add   \ Change  
  Stats               \ Change
```

This is because we manipulated the dictionary used to render the template and it uses the values we specified, in this case the most relevant is the `name` **Stats**, the `admin_url` which will call the custom view `stats`. Since we left `add_url` empty, there will be no **+ Add** link displayed.

Important is also the penultimate line, where we call our custom admin and pass it a name, it will be used as a url namespace.

EDIT:
Unfortunately I noticed only after posting the answer that the question is asking how to display a link for a custom view created in a `ModelAdmin`, whereas my answer explains how to do this for a custom admin `AdminSite`. I hope it still of some help.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old but I had the same issue and I found a simpler (yet maybe messier) way of doing it, that doesn't involve overriding templates or methods.

I just created a proxy model in **models.py** such as:

```
class Proxy(models.Model):

    id = models.BigAutoField(db_column='id', primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "<Label: id: %d>" % self.id

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        verbose_name_plural = 'proxies'
        db_table = 'proxy'
        ordering = ('id',)
```

Which is just a **mysql view** that a created from am existing table

```
 create view proxy
    as select id
    from samples
    LIMIT 10;
```

And finally in **admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Proxy)
class LabelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'label_view.html'
    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
      ...
        return render(request, "label_view.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not a good way, but you can try overriding the default index.html of the django admin as :

```
   {% for model in app.models %}
        <tr class="model-{{ model.object_name|lower }}">
        {% if model.admin_url %}
            <th scope="row"><a href="{{ model.admin_url }}">{{ model.name }}</a></th>
        {% else %}
            <th scope="row">{{ model.name }}</th>
        {% endif %}

        {% if model.add_url %}
            <td><a href="{{ model.add_url }}" class="addlink">{% trans 'Add' %}</a></td>
        {% else %}
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        {% endif %}

        {% if model.admin_url %}
            <td><a href="{{ model.admin_url }}" class="changelink">{% trans 'Change' %}</a></td>
        {% else %}
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        {% endif %}
        </tr>

   {% endfor %}
    <!-- extra link you want to display -->
    <tr>
    <th scope="row"><a href="link_url">link_name</a></th>
    <td><a href="link_url" class="changelink">{% trans 'Change' %}</a></td>
    </tr>
```

After overriding this block put index.html inside your templates/admin directory of your project. Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution cannot be realized with an app but only with the project template folder, correct?

Comment: Yes, it need to be overridden for the entire project.

Comment: Okay, this could eventually be a "work-around" if we'll not find any app-based answer.

Comment: Any other cleaner way to achieve this ?